# C++ function to convert a symbol to Unicode code point?

Tags: c++, c++11

How can I convert a symbol to unicode? If I enter `Ķ`, `U+0136` should be printed:

```
std::string a;
std::cin >> a;           // Type "Ķ"
std::cout << unicode(a); // Prints "U+0136"
```

Comment: What is `unicode`?

Comment: @Acorn this is the function OP wants but doesn't have.

Comment: It very much depends on your OS and compiler. C++ has very poor built-in Unicode support.

Comment: @n.m. Ah, I see, thank you. Edited a bit...

Comment: @Eljay your sourceforge link is rather useless here. The biggest problem is getting *anything* in `a` if your input is the console and your link doesn't address that at all.

Comment: What is your OS? Does reading a UTF-8 string from a terminal work to begin with?

Comment: You can use `std::cout << std::hex << static_cast<unsigned int>(a[0] + 256) << ' ' << static_cast<unsigned int>(a[1] + 256);` to get the UTF-8 value (0xC4 0xB6) but I don't know how to convert it to UTF-16 (0x0136) https://wandbox.org/permlink/s7lkBWvX5wDGvZG0

Comment: Here is an example for a unicode with two bytes: https://wandbox.org/permlink/LquFWoiR668Yai4o The other cases should be no problem with https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-8

Comment: See examples in https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/locale/codecvt